# maximum distribution with weighed edges

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Imagine a graph where each vertex has a value (example, number of stones) and is connected through edges, that represents the cost of traversing that edge in stones. I want to find the largest possible amount of stones, such that each vertex Vn >= this value. Vertices can can exchange stones to others, but the value exchanged gets subtracted by the distance, or weight of the edges connecting them

I need to solve this as a greedy algorithm and in O(n) complexity, where n is the amount of vertices, but I have problems identifying the subproblems/greedy choice. I was hoping that someone could provide a stepping stone or some hints on how to accomplish this, much appreciated

Comment: Some first thoughts: The average of the vertex values is the theoretical maximum you can achieve. The vertex with the least value determines the overall quality. Maybe this vertex should take the stones from the richest neighbour? It's probably not that trivial (nor `O(n)`). Every time you transport stones, the maximum quality decreases by `edge_weight/n`. In my thinking I stumbled across pathfinding again and again. Maybe a variation of Dijkstra can be of some help (Dijkstra uses a greedy strategy).

Comment: Yes but before I look at that, i need to identify the subproblems, which I havent been able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary of Question

I am not sure I have understood the question correctly, so first I will summarize my understanding.

1. We have a graph with vertices v1,v2,..,vn and weighted edges. Let the weight between vi and vj be W[i,j]
2. Each vertex starts with a number of stones, let us call the number of stones on vertex vi equal to A[i]
3. You wish to perform multiple transfers in order to maximise the value of min(A[i] for i = 1..n)
4. x stones can be transferred between vi and vj if x>W[i,j], this operation transforms the values as:

> ```
>  A[i] -= x
>  A[j] += x-W[i,j]  # Note fewer stones arrive than leave
> ```

Is this correct?

## Response

I believe this problem is NP-hard because it can be used to solve [3-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SAT#3-satisfiability), a known NP-complete problem.

For a 3-sat example with M clauses such as:

```
(A+B+!C).(B+C+D)
```

Construct a directed graph which has a node for each clause (with no stones), a node for each variable with 3M+1 stones, and two auxiliary nodes for each variable with 1 stone (one represents the variable having a positive value, and one represents the variable having a negative value.

Then connect the nodes as shown below:

[image]

This graph will have a solution with all vertices having value >= 1, if and only if the 3-sat is soluble.

The point is that each red node (e.g. for variable A) can only send stones to either A=1 or A=0, but not both.  If we provide stones to the green node A=1, then this node can supply stones to all of the blue clauses which use that variable in a positive sense.

(Your original question does not involve a directed graph, but I doubt that this additional change will make a material difference to the complexity of the problem.)

### Summary

I am afraid it is going to be very hard to get an O(n) solution to this problem.